# PHP Simple HTML DOM return gibberish when website enable caching

Tags: php, web-scraping, caching

```
include('/simple_html_dom.php');

$url = "https://www.2311666.com.tw/";
$opts = array(
   'http'=> array('header'=>"User-Agent:Chrome/94.0.4606.81\r\n"));
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$get = file_get_contents($url,false,$context);
$html->load($get);

echo $html;
```

P.S. The above code is deployed on the server.

I've no problem scraping most of websites but some specific sites with WordPress internal caching return gibberish.

To be more precise, **the first crawl is normal** but **second crawl show gibberish**.

I've tried using cURL or dynamic User-Agent but get the same result. Is there a correct way?

Answer (score 0):

Use cURL and add curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING, "")
Or gzdecode() function could solve the problem.